# FileHelpers library CSV - why is one letter always removed from the last column on the right?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, import, filehelpers

I have found a really great library to read CSV files - **[FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com)**, but I have a strange problem with it. I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance !

**After mapping, I always get one letter removed from the last column on the right.**

I'm using FileHelpers.dll Version 2.0.0 - DotNet 2.0 from `FileHelpers_2_0_0_bin_docs_wizard.zip`

For e.g. I have a CSV like this (some columns are quoted but some are not, it may change)

```
name;surname
"John";Smith
"Jack";Baker
```

And after reading file with:

```
FileHelperEngine<SemicolonsRow> engine = new FileHelperEngine<SemicolonsRow>();
engine.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;

res = engine.ReadFile("C:\\a.txt");

if (engine.ErrorManager.ErrorCount > 0)
engine.ErrorManager.SaveErrors("C:\\Log.txt");
```

I get this:

```
res[0].Col0 with name
res[0].Col1 with surnam  (lack of e at the end)
res[1].Col0 with John
res[1].Col0 with Smit  (lack of h at the end)
```

When I read file like this:

```
name;surname;country
"John";Smith;USA
"Jack";Baker;Canada
```

the problem is in third column - so I get: `countr US Canad`

My FileHelpers class:

```
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
public sealed class SemicolonsRow
{
    [FieldOptional()]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForRead, MultilineMode.AllowForRead)]
    public String Col0;

    [FieldOptional()]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForRead, MultilineMode.AllowForRead)]
    public String Col1;

    [FieldOptional()]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForRead, MultilineMode.AllowForRead)]
    public String Col2;

    [FieldOptional()]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForRead, MultilineMode.AllowForRead)]
    public String Col3;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Does this occur when the source file doesn't include quoted fields?

Comment: @Simon Whittemore - Yes, when I have all columns without any quotes I also get cut words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an old issue with opcional fields and some other conditions that was solved after the release but we never get time to a full release

You can download the last stable version from here that solve the problem:

http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=lastSuccessful&buildTypeId=bt66&tab=artifacts&guest=1

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The newer version solved my problem so thanks for professional support. I recommend the FileHelpers library with a clear conscience :)

Comment: Marcos, it would be awesome if you put the link to the Teamcity build on the filehelpers.com website.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the library is expecting the delimiter to appear as the last character.
Contact the author of the library.

Comment: Well, the project is open source and contains unit tests, so I'd start there.